# How Do I Get My Project To Recognize Remember and MutableStateOf?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to make use of the following code:

```
var a by remember {
mutableStateOf("")
}
```

When I put that code in my project. Both remember and mutableStateOf is red. My project doesn't recognize what they are. I think I have to import something or add a dependency, but I am not sure what or how to do this.

Comment: Those are from Jetpack Compose: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot imports.

`by` it is kotlin [operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/keyword-reference.html#soft-keywords). You have to import it.

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
```